# CSS override on Eric Meyers Reset

Tags: html, css, font-size, reset

I am trying to change the font size of the h1 element, however it doesn't appear to override the reset CSS file. I have had some luck with defining the style twice, but that doesn't seem like the most elegant solution. Thanks.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Here is my CSS.

```
@import url('reset.css');
@import url('grid.css');
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700);

body{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

// Headers

h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Can you demo the problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
// Headers

h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

`// Headers` is not a valid way of marking up comments in CSS – and because of that *error*, the following rule can not be parsed.

Make that a *real* CSS comment, `/* Headers */`, and it should work fine.

And next time, please *validate* your code before asking – doing so would have told you that already.